# Find the first non-exist value in DynamoDB (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to send a user for the first available cabin in a store.

Here is my Dynamodb table with 'cabin_number' as a partition key.

```
| cabin_number |  user_id  |
|     1        |   John    |
|     2        |           |
|     3        |           |
|     4        |   Mark    |
```

My Lambda function:

```
import boto3
import json

dynamoDB = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamoDB.Table("ab3-cabin_number")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.put_item(
    Item={
        'cabin_number': "2",
        'user_id': event
        },
     ConditionExpression = "attribute_not_exists(user_id)",
 )
```

I am able check directly 'cabin_number'= 2 but I would like that Dynamodb verify one cabin per time until find the first available to receive a new user. I tried to call another function using **for loops**, but it did not work.

Note 1: If I use scan, it returned all the empty cabin but I need only the first one.

Note 2: My API will send only the user_id (event = user_id).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDBs which are basically JSON objects do not support these type of complex operations.

Other options:

1. Using an SQL db where it is efficient to query such data
2. In-memory list to store all the data and loop over it to find the cabin

List implementation:

```
n_cabins = 10
Cabins = [None] * n_cabins
Cabin_info = {}
start_index = 0
def fill_cabin(user):
    idx = start_index
    while(Cabins[idx]):
        idx += 1
    
    Cabin_info[user] = idx
    Cabins[idx] = user
    
def empty_cabin(user):
    idx = Cabin_info.pop(user)
    Cabins[idx] = None
    global start_index
    start_index = idx if idx < start_index else start_index
```

There are a lot of different datastructures you can use to optimise this even further like maintaining a min heap of indices.